# python wait nth digit before continue

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio

# Setup Keypad
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

ROW_PINS = [5,6,13,19] # BCM numbering
COL_PINS = [26,16,20,21] # BCM numbering

factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)

def processKey(key):
 print("enter 3 digit")
 print(key)
 if key == 123:
  print("correct")
 else:
  print("wrong password")

keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(processKey)
```

I want the code to wait for the user enter for example 3 digits before comparing with the password in the code which is 123 in above code.

**What it should do:**

Wait user enter 3 digit from the keypad , for example 123 , then print correct.

**What it actually do:**

it will print correct or incorrect password straight away after user enter 1 digit code

Comment: check `if len(key) == 3:` But you have to keep `key` in global value and append new char.

Answer (score 1):

Update for raspberry taking @furas example:

```
# Initial keypad setup
code = ''

def processKey(key):
    print("Enter your 3 digit PWD: \n")
    global code
    MAX_ALLOWED_CHAR = 3
    code += key
    if (len(code) == MAX_ALLOWED_CHAR):
        if (code == "123"): 
            print("You entered the correct code.")
            dostuff()
        else:
            code = ''        
            print("The passcode you entered is wrong, retry.")

def dostuff():
    # do your things here since passcode is correct.
```

This might do it for your case.

---

```
def processKey():

    key = input("enter 3 digit")
    if (key == "123"):
        print("Correct password.")
        return True
    else:
        print("You typed {0} wich is incorrect.".format(key))
        return False
```

So now you don't give processKey a value because as you said the user input it, calling processKey() will ask the user to enter a password and return true/false based on the "123" in the check.

This is if you want to input the password, but if the following answer is not suiting your needs (didn't quite fully understand what you want to accomplish) just provide more clever example.

Edit:

Since you wanted to strictly have a 3 digit input and a re-input password in case they enter the wrong one you can do the following:

On the call to processKey() you can:

```
while (processKey() == False):
    processKey()
```

Revisioned code to match your needs:

```
def processKey():
    MAX_ALLOWED_CHAR = 3
    key = input("Enter 3 digit PWD: \n")
    if (key == 123):
        print("Correct password.")
        return True
    elif (len(str(key)) > MAX_ALLOWED_CHAR):
        print("The max allowed character is {0}, instead you entered {1}.".format(MAX_ALLOWED_CHAR,key))
        return False
    else:
        print("You typed {0} wich is incorrect.".format(key))
        return False

while (processKey() == False):
    processKey()
```

Output:

```
Enter 3 digit PWD: 
3333
The max allowed character is 3, instead you entered 3333.
Enter 3 digit PWD: 
321
You typed 321 wich is incorrect.
Enter 3 digit PWD: 
123
Correct password.
```

Comment: i would like the python programe to take three digits password from a keypad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will work with a normal keyboard but i am using a 4x4 matrix keypad on a raspberry pi.

Comment: Look again, code updated. Sorry but i didn't see you specify the raspberry thing

Answer (score 1):

keypress is executed after every key press - and it is natural. You have to keep all keys on list or in string and check its length.

```
code = ''

def processKey(key):
    global code

    code += key

    if len(code) == 3:
        if code == "123": 
           print("correct")
        else:
           print("wrong password, try again")
           code = ''
```

Comment: if the password is incorrect, how to  programe it back to ask password state?